# Poisson interaval times intersection with there being 2 arrivals

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is a poisson process N with rate $\lambda$. $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the first and second arrival times.

How do you calculate $$P(T_1 \le t_1 , T_2 \le t_2 , N_t=2) $$

Comment: So you can write $\{N_t=2\}$ as $\{T_2<t<T_3\}$

That would allow you to write $P(T_1 \le t_1 , T_2 \le t_1 , T_2<t<T_3)$. Still not sure how to procede

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use the inter-arrival times and the fact that they are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Conditionally on $[N_t=2]$, the set $\{T_1,T_2\}$ is distributed as $\{U,V\}$ with $U$ and $V$ i.i.d. and uniform on $[0,t]$. In particular, for every $0\lt s\lt r\lt t$,
$$
\mathbb P(s\lt T_1,T_2\lt r\mid N_t=2)=\mathbb P(U\in[s,r],V\in[s,r])=t^{-2}(r-s)^2.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathbb P(s\lt T_1,r\lt T_2\mid N_t=2)=t^{-2}((t-s)^2-(r-s)^2).
$$
Finally, $N_t$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda t$ hence $\mathbb P(N_t=2)=\tfrac12\lambda^2t^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}$ and
$$
\mathbb P(s\lt T_1,r\lt T_2,N_t=2)=\tfrac12\lambda^2\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}((t-s)^2-(r-s)^2).
$$